# How to add a Cache-Control header to my static files hosted on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I want to enable browser caching of images, css and java script files.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers

The heroku article says this in its conclusion:

*"Once the concepts behind HTTP caching are understood the next step is to implement them in your application. Most modern web frameworks make this a trivial task."*

Can someone tell me how to do this trivial task? I have a django-python app.

Answer (score 2):

The static files like images, css and javascript should be served directly by the webserver (e.g. Apache of nginx), not by Django. Therefore you should configure any caching in your web server configuration, not Django.

If you are hosting your Django project on Heroku, they appear to recommend [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) according to [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets).

Comment: I've hosted my app on Heroku. This link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers says that my web framework should handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Your static resources should really be served from a webserver such as nginx or apache and not directly from django but to answer your question, django inlcudes a `staticfiles` app which one assumes you are using to manage those resources, if so, use

`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'`

in your `settings.py` file to enable django's caching for staticfiles.

c.f 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cachedstaticfilesstorage 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cachedstaticfilesstorage

[the 1.6 link has more explanation of how this works]

For caching as a whole in django, I recommend reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/ 
where you can see how to use middleware for site level caching or the `cache_control` decorator for view-caching like so:

from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

`@cache_control(must_revalidate=True, max_age=3600)
def my_view(request):
    # ...`